# Writing to a new line in python in append mode

Tags: python, file-io, append, newline

how can i append to a new line for an existing file in python ?

my code is :

```
        status_done="Completed"
        f = open("%s\%s%s" % (path,self.filename,filelog_ext),"a")
        data=("%s \r" % status_done)        
        f.writelines(data)
```

i tried \r , \n , both \r\n
none of them work, it always appends to the end of the existing line

here's the output it gave me:

line1:http://www.md5.comCompleted

i want the Completed to be on a new line i.e:

line1:http://www.md5.com

line2:Completed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how bout

```
data="\r\n%s" % status_done  
f.write(data)
```

as further explanation you were adding your newline AFTER your "Completed" ... this just moves the newline to BEFORE your string so that your string appears on the newline

Comment: This will probably be more efficient if you make this into a `tuple` or if OP just uses `f.write`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
with open("File.txt", "ab") as myfile:
```

"ab" will make it append in binary mode which includes escaped line chars.